# Use physical buttons to take picture when camera is open

Tags: camera, buttons

Is there an app or other way to use the physical buttons on my phone to take a picture when the camera is open? (I see various apps to open the camera using those buttons, but not to take a picture). It would be a lot easier than trying to tap the screen while using only one hand.

(It's a Motorola G8 that I have if that is relevant).

Comment: Not that I know (which must not mean a thing). But some camera apps give you such option in their settings, like assigning what vol+/- shall do (zoom in/out or take a picture, for example). IIRC, e.g. OpenCamera has such.

Comment: On most phones you can use the Google Assistant too.  "*OK Google take a picture*".